# Format mysql row output for array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm taking a data set from a database, there are three fields being pulled, the ID, a name, and a count.

I am using mysqli_fetch_array to extract the data.

I need to get a single array in a format similar to this:

```
array (
  64 => 
  array (
    0 => 'bandsaw',
    1 => '9',
  ),
  52 => 
  array (
    0 => 'drill',
    1 => '15',
  ),
  102 => 
  array (
    0 => 'hammer',
    1 => '38',
  ),
)
```

The keys are random as the data taken from the database is sorted based on the name rather than the ID.

I've tried things like:

```
$resources[] = $row['ResourceID'];
$resources[]['name'] = $row['ResourceDescription'];
$resources[]['count'] = $row['Resource_Count'];
```

But that gives unwanted results.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Sorry about that, edited it in.  I need to get the data set into an array with example format above, key(value1, value2), key2(value1, value2) etc.

Comment: Why all the down votes?  I know I didn't word it brilliantly but still...

Comment: Not really sure, probably from before your edit. People seem awfully keen to downvote questions (and less inclined to upvote) it seems, just the culture of SO unfortunately. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$return = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $return[$row['id']] = array($row['name'], $row['count']);
}
```